# The most amazing JavaScript application ever

Tags: javascript

I just saw the [Google Pacmen](http://www.google.com/) game and I think it's the most professional JavaScript application that I ever saw!

What other application do you know about, that are in this level of profession?

Comment: I tried to sew the Google Pacmen but they kept running away from my needle.

Comment: @Snake took me a while to understand what do you want... :)

Comment: @Snake Plissken: a jquery evangelist would advise you to .bind the needle

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may want to check out [Chrome Experiments](http://www.chromeexperiments.com/) and [Processing JS](http://processingjs.org/exhibition) for some impressive stuff.

Or what about a [JavaScript port of Wolfenstein 3D](http://www.javascriptgaming.com/2009/03/javascript-wolfenstein-3d.html)? ... Or this [3D Tetris clone called Torus](http://www.benjoffe.com/code/games/torus/)?

Comment: The "Harmony" experiment on that page is really cool.

Comment: Wow... what an amazing staff... too many...

Comment: I'm totally going to try to write Torus this summer.  I'm an avid Tetris fan